# How can I write a regular expression that matches a number of characters dependent on what has already been matched?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So, I want to parse input text that uses fixed-width formatting. As an example, consider:

> KEYWORD = value / Comment text

The keyword part of the text is 8 characters, left justified and space padded. 
If there is a `=` in column 9 then the next part is a value, followed by an optional comment preceded with a single '/'
If there is no `=` in column 9 then the remainder of the line is a comment.
Each line consists of exactly 80 space padded characters.
(FYI this is part of the NASA FITS format).

So, for the keyword part, I want to match a total of 8 characters consisting of X valid keyword characters followed by (8 - X) spaces. Valid keyword characters are digits, upper case characters, hyphen and underscore. The number of trailing spaces that are present must be 8 minus the number of valid keyword characters, so the quantifier for the expression matching the spaces needs to be derived from the number of valid keyword characters already matched.

The standard quantifiers make it easy to match things like "one or more", "zero or more" and so on, but in my case the exact number is important and is not constant (it depends on what has already been matched).

I suppose one way to do it would be by making lots of alternatives, so the keywords could be:

1 character followed by 7 spaces, or
2 characters followed by 6 spaces, etc.

```
([0-9A-Z-_]{1} {7})|([0-9A-Z-_]{2} {6})|...etc)
```

That gets unmanageable very quickly and it will be worse later when trying to match a Value + Comment which is in a fixed width field of 69 characters. I think I have to rule this approach out.

Is there a way to do this kind of matching in .NET regular expressions, where the length of one match depends on the length of a previous match?

Comment: Couldn't you just copy the first 8 characters of the string and then apply your validation only to them?

Comment: "fixed-width formatting" - I wouldn't go the regex way. I'd prefer the Substring and [] functionalities of string, that's far easier. Also think of the poor guy who will have to maintain that code - will he be able to follow such a complicated regex. Note: that poor guy might be you yourself just a few month later...

Comment: It's not actually fixed width formatting, there are lots of ifs and buts. If the field is there, then it must be 8 space padded characters, but it can be absent or there might just be a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this kind of matching in .NET regular expressions, where the length of one match depends on the length of a previous match?

No.

Each match has no knowledge of the previous match nor the length of a previous. The only exception is to match the **text only** of a specific back reference (see [Numbered Backreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions#numbered-backreferences)) that is available for similar repeating text patterns.

---

To do such an operation, I recommend to do a multistep programmatic process, where the first step is to tokenize the text to its smallest unit, while the second operation takes those tokens and applies the rules as you prescribed to produce output.